# Translate function to replace the spaces in between the special character in xml in xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, whitespace, translate

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<section>
<Notes>~ CB:C86100011~ NAME:THINKPAD LAPTOP 10~ PART_DESCRIPTION:FD85 FLOOR DRY 25-LB POLY BAG WITH HANDLE~ POL:1~ Price:6.163965~ UnitsofMeasure:EA~ VN:FD85~</Notes>
</section>
```

xslt trying to remove spaces with the ~ value

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Output>
          <xsl:value-of select="translate(section/Notes,'~ ','~')"/>
</Output>
```

Current Output like below . It's even removing the spaces from the string value

```
<Output>~CB:C86100011~NAME:THINKPADLAPTOP10~PART_DESCRIPTION:FD85FLOORDRY25-LBPOLYBAGWITHHANDLE~POL:1~Price:6.163965~UnitsofMeasure:EA~VN:FD85~</Output>
```

but excepted out should be expeting the remove the after of the ~ like below..

```
<Notes>~CB:C86100011~NAME:THINKPAD LAPTOP 10~PART_DESCRIPTION:FD85 FLOOR DRY 25-LB POLY BAG WITH HANDLE~POL:1~Price:6.163965~UnitsofMeasure:EA~VN:FD85~</Notes>
```

Comment: `translate` replaces **individual** characters (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-translate); you'll to use `replace` instead (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-replace)

Comment: Thanks @Fravadona.. After using the repalce it's worked.
 <Output>
          <xsl:value-of select="replace(section/Notes,'~ ','~')"/>
    </Output>